# Can you transfer data from a v-for loop into a chart?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, vuejs2, apexcharts

I am building charts using vue2, Axios and ApexCharts.

The official documentation for ApexCharts suggest that I get the data into the chart using Update.

```js
axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: url,
}).then(function(response) {
  chart.updateSeries([{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: response.data
  }])
})
```

But this is not gonna work for me, because the data I am getting is stored in a object with multiple nested objects and arrays.
I AM able to get the data using v-for

```js
<template>

   <b-container class="my-4">

   <tbody>
      <tr v-for="stat in bIGraphStats.propertyStatsPerMonth">
         <td v-text="stat.date"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>

</template>
      
<script>

  export default {
    data: () => ({
      bIGraphStats: null,
    }),
    methods: {
      getInfo(){
      const self = this;
        axios.get(`bi/stats/property/company`, {timeout: 300000})
            .then(response => {
              this.bIGraphStats = response.data
            })
            .catch(error => this.bIGraphStats = error.data);
      },
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getInfo()
    }
  };

</script>
```

So I am wondering. Is there some way I can get around this by passing the data from the v-for loop into my chart?
For example in my loop I am getting the dates from a specific array

```
<td v-text="stat.date"></td>
```

So in my chart, I would like to do something like this:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({

    series: [],
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        height: 350
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [stat.date],
      }
    }
  }),
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: There's no reason to pass anything from v-for because it operates with the same data that is already available in the component. It's unclear how v-for is related with a chart. There is no chart in that component

Comment: Maybay use map function or forEach to create array for apexcharts from response data. [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)